# EF Update sub entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have the following classes

#1

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string wId { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string Code { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string Ean { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "DECIMAL(10,2)")]
    public decimal Price { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "INT")]
    public int Vat { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "TINYINT")]
    public bool Stockable { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "TINYINT")]
    public bool Produced { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string Unit { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "DECIMAL(10,2)")]
    public decimal Netto { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "DECIMAL(10,2)")]
    public decimal Brutto { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string Description { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "DECIMAL(10,2)")]
    public decimal QuantityGlobal { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "TINYINT")]
    public bool HalfProduct { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "DATETIME")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "DATETIME")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; protected set; }
    public ProductParameters ProductParameters { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "INT")]
    public int CompanyId { get; protected set; }
```

#2

```
public class ProductParameters
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string Size { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string Width { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string Length { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "INT")]
    public ProductCategory Category { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "INT")]
    public ProductPattern Pattern { get; protected set; }
    public ProductParameters()
```

#3

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(MAX)")]
    public string NamePL { get; protected set; }
```

I can update the ProductParameter and Product class with EF, but the ProductCategory class that is a child of ProductParameters cannot

Context Code

```
try
        {
            var oldproduct = testcontext.Product.Where(x => x.Id == product.Id).Include(x => x.ProductParameters).Include(p => p.ProductParameters.Category).Include(k => k.ProductParameters.Pattern).FirstOrDefault();
            if (oldproduct != null)
            {
                
                testcontext.Entry(oldproduct).CurrentValues.SetValues(product);
                testcontext.Entry(oldproduct.ProductParameters).CurrentValues.SetValues(product.ProductParameters);
                testcontext.Entry(oldproduct.ProductParameters.Category).CurrentValues.SetValues(product.ProductParameters.Category)
                testcontext.SaveChanges();
                return oldproduct;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
```

How can I actually update this? I need to set only Id, without creating new model.
For now I know how to update Product and ProductParameters, I tried various things I found on the internet

Comment: Please show what you have done so far. What do you need to update? Pls show the view.  And action where you create model for the view too., I have neve seen the view that contains parent model and all nested models together. And show the update action too.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update `Id` of `ProductCategory` table, then that is not possible as it is primary key and `Identity` column. In this case if you need to update that column then take a new column in table (like `ProductCategoryCode`) and make that primary key and identity column and remove constrains from `Id` column.